# Setting multiple values to a object

Tags: javascript

I want to set multiple objects as multiple values of another object. So for example

```
let dataObj ={}
const personData = {name:"sai",age:"20"}
const ids = {id1:"1231455",id2:"425325232"}
dataObj.personData = personData;
dataObj.ids = ids
console.log(dataObj);
```

'personData' is a object and 'ids' is a object.Im setting these 2 objects as 2 values for 'dataObj'.
I was wondering is there a shorter way to achieve this like:

```
let dataObj ={}
const personData = {name:"sai",age:"20"}
const ids = {id1:"1231455",id2:"425325232"}
dataObj = personData;
dataObj = ids
console.log(dataObj);
```

The problem with the alternative I suggested is that it wont set 'key' of 'dataObj' object.It will just set the values of 'personData' and 'ids' to the value of dataObj.Is there any way I can achieve this ? Specifying multiple objects as values to another object with keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
let dataObj = {};

const personData = {name:"sai",age:"20"}
const ids = {id1:"1231455",id2:"425325232"}

dataObj = { ...dataObj, personData, ids };

console.log(dataObj);

/*
output : 
value of dataObj:
{
  personData: {
    name: "sai",
    age" "20"
  },
  ids: {
    id1: "1231455",
    id2: "425325232"
  }
}
*/
```

I'll try and explain spread using the above example. First we start with an empty object `dataObj`: `{}`. We want to *add* new properties to that object: `personData` with the `personData` object as value and `ids` with the `ids` object as value.

ES2015 added a shorthand syntax for setting property definitions in objects. That's what been used here:

```
dataObj = { personData, ids };
```

This is simply a cleaner way of writing

```
dataObj = {
  personData: personData,
  ids: ids
};
```

More info on this can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Because you want to initialise your object before, we can't simply overwrite the object, but we need to add the new properties to the existing object. This can be done using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```
const oldObject = { key: 'value', anotherKey: 'another value' };
let newObject = { ...oldObject };
// newObject value: { key: 'value', anotherKey: 'another value' };
```

The `oldObject` was 'spreaded' in `newObject`. Resulting it in having the same key-value pairs as `oldObject`.
In your code example we assign a *new* object to `dataObj`. In that new object we spread all properties which are in the current `dataObj`: `{ ...dataObj` and then add the new properties: `, personData, ids }`.

I hope this explanation is clear, feel free to ask for more info. The spread syntax is very powerful and can be used for a lot of things. So be sure to read up on that.

Comment: I want to declare a empty object and then add objects to it.

Comment: @EaGLE That's what this answer does, it's just compressed to a single line.

Comment: @EaGLE I've updated my code so that's reflected clearly.

Comment: Yes @LuudJacobs It works.But if you dont mind can you please explain to me dat how it is done.I know that "..."  spread operator is used to copy something.Over that I did not understand.

Comment: @EaGLE Sure, I'll update my answer. If this answer helped you, could you please mark it as answer?

Comment: Yes sure I tried as soon as it worked but it asked me to wait 2mins

Comment: @LuudJacobs Thank you, I understood it.Your explination is very good.

Answer (score -1):

You can merge two objects as below. You can use '...' spread object. the spread object works for objects as well. Clone an object as shown in below code. for more information please visit https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-spread-operator/

```js
let dataObj = {}
    const personData = { name: "sai", age: "20" }
    const ids = { id1: "1231455", id2: "425325232" }
    dataObj = { ...dataObj, personData, ids }
    console.log(dataObj);
```

Comment: If you feel my answer is correct and it helps you. Please mark it as a right.

Comment: Using the spread syntax will 'unpack' the inner objects, which is not what the OP requested

Comment: @EaGLE, I have added a description about the spread object(...).

Comment: @Rajan Thanks for your reference to the answer.